# Find the correct path in array

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I have a list of amounts in different currencies and I have to translate them to the EUR currency.

I also have an array of objects representing various exchange rates, but not all the currencies have a direct exchange rate to EUR.

Example:

```
EUR - USD - 1.359
USD - EUR - 0.736
CAD - USD - 0.932
USD - CAD - 1.200
NTD - CAD - 0.345
```

In this example if I want to get from NTD to EUR I'll have to do NTD->CAD first, then CAD->USD and finally USD->EUR.

The number of steps is not predetermined, it could be one or more steps to get to EUR.

How can I do it in Swift 5? I'm able to do it if there's only one step from one currency to EUR, but I get lost if there are more.

EDIT adding some code.

This is the object 'Rate' in my model class:

```
struct Rate: Decodable {
    let curFrom: String
    let curTo: String
    let curRate: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case curFrom = "from"
        case curTo = "to"
        case curRate = "rate"
    }
}
```

And this is the function I was making when I thought that I could need more than two steps to get to the EUR currency:

```
func sumTransactions() -> Double {
        var total: Double = 0
        itemTransactions.forEach { (transaction) in
            if transaction.currency == "EUR" {
                if let amount = Double(transaction.amount) {
                    total += amount
                }
            } else {
                let foundRates = rates.filter({$0.curTo == "EUR" && $0.curFrom == transaction.currency})
                if foundRates.count > 0 {
                    if let amount = Double(transaction.amount), let rate = Double(foundRates.first!.curRate) {
                        total += amount * rate
                    }
                } else {
                    let foundAltRates = rates.filter({$0.curFrom == transaction.currency})
                    if foundAltRates.count > 0 {
                        let foundRates = foundAltRates.filter({$0.curTo == "EUR"})
                        if foundRates.count > 0 {
                            //
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        
        return total
    }
```

The object "transaction" has two properties: "amount" and "currency". At the end I'll have to sum all the amounts but in the EUR currency.

Comment: Where is your code? Please add the definition of Rate and also your own attempt at solving this?

Comment: What is the “correct path” if there are different ways to convert one currency into another? That is not a Swift question.

Comment: You might be interested into "Nodes", "Tree", and how to find a value from there. But by doing multiple pre-operations, you might loose some precision.

Comment: This is a really classic graph problem. Your nodes are currencies, and the arcs between them are exchange rates path between two currencies you want to exchange. Your exchange rates work like a distance function, so you can use a depth first search to find the cheapest rate. You can also "compress" the graph into a minimum spanning tree, and that lets you convert between any supported currencies using the minimum number of steps (but not necessarily the best rate)

Comment: I've added some code for you to see. @Alexander I'm not interested in finding the best rate, but only the minimum number of steps.

Comment: https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftGraph might be useful

Comment: @MartinR I just need the fastest way to convert one currency into another (less number of steps).

Comment: @Shadowrun that seems very interesting. Thank you.

Comment: Does the number of steps matter for the problem? (e.g., exchanging currencies incurs a fee of some sort?) or are you just trying to convert various currencies to EUR?

Comment: @NickKim Just trying to convert to EUR.

Comment: In that case, I think the problem can be simplified if you update all your exchange rates to convert to EUR (e.g., USD-EUR, NTD-EUR, ... )

Comment: @NickKim The exchange rates come from a REST service. If you mean after fetching the exchange rates to update them to be all converted to EUR, that's just what I don't know how to do (if there are more than two steps).

Comment: @Aleph72 I think you *completely* missing the graph-structure of this problem. You're hard coding the number of conversion steps, and that's doomed to fail unless you can guarantee what exchange rates exist.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the idea that the problem at hand could be simplified by simply converting all the exchange rates to EUR, we fetch the rates from the REST service, and flatten the rates to EUR

```
enum Currencies: String {
    case euro = "EUR"
    case usd = "USD"
    ...
}

// * -> EUR
var simplifiedRates: [String: Double] = [Currencies.euro.rawValue: 1.0]
var fetchedRates: Set<Rate> = service.fetchRateSet()


for rate in fetchedRates {
    if rate.curTo == Currencies.euro.rawValue {
        simplifiedRates[rate.curFrom] = rate.curRate
        fetchedRates.remove(rate)
    }
}

while !fetchedRates.isEmpty {
    for rate in fetchedRates {
        if let existingRate = simplifiedRates[rate.curTo] {
            simplifiedRates[rate.curFrom] = existingRate * rate.curRate
            fetchedRates.remove(rate)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that since we are comparing all that point towards EUR, all other exchange rates MUST have a target currency that is convertable to EUR. (e.g., KRW -> USD requires USD -> EUR to make KRW -> EUR work)

```
...
fetchedRates.insert(Rate(curFrom: "USD", curTo: "EUR", curRate: 0.736))
fetchedRates.insert(Rate(curFrom: "CAD", curTo: "USD", curRate: 0.932))
print(simplifiedRates)
```

```
> ["USD": 0.736, "CAD": 0.685952, "EUR": 1.0]
```

Then the `sumTransactions` can be neatly written as such

```
func sumTransactions() -> Double { 
    var total: Double = 0
    for transaction in itemTransactions {
        total += simplifiedRates[transaction.currency] * transaction.amount
    }
    return total
}
```

Comment: Your solution, if I got it right, only works if the conversion requires an intermediate step, for example USD -> CAD -> EUR (in the case we don't have a direct USD to EUR exchange rate). The problem is that I don't know how many steps I could need to exchange one random currency to EUR.

Comment: Since we're iterating over the `fetchedRates` set until it's empty, anything that could eventually be converted to EUR will get flattened. e.g, KRW -> CAD, CAD -> JPY, JPY -> USD,  USD -> EUR will neatly get flattened

Comment: I'll try it and let you know. Thanks.